# Python: Replace one cell in a CSV file

Tags: python, csv

I have a CSV file that has a single cell that I want to edit.

I can write a pretty simple function that, for instance, can look up an ID field in the file and return the row of the ID in question:

```
id = 3 #column number of the ID field

csvfile = open(os.path.join(LOCAL_FOLDER, "csvfile.csv"), "rU")
csvFile= csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=",")

def lookup(ID):
    rowNo = 1
    for row in csvFile:
        if row[id] == ID:
            return rowNo
        else:
            rowNo += 1
    return 0
```

What I want to do is to write a corresponding `replace` function that will take in an `ID`, a `column` variable and a `data` variable:

```
def replace(ID, col, data):
    row = lookup(ID)
    #use a CSV writer to replace the item at row, col with data
```

I have no idea how to do this, all of the examples I can find for how to use the writer only show you how to completely rewrite an entire .CSV file, which is not what I'm looking to do; I want an equivalent of a `PUT` rather than a `POST`.

Comment: It can be done ONLY IF `ID` and `data` are made up of the same number of bytes

Comment: So does that mean that I basically have to completely rewrite the CSV file on a replace?

Comment: yup! If you are concerned about reading the entire file into memory, you could write to another file. The alternative is to simultaneously read and write (to make up for the extra bytage), which is very unadvisable

Answer (score 0):

fwiw, per inspectorG4dget's suggestion, I rewrote my code as follows:

```
LOCAL_FOLDER = os.getcwd()
CSV_FILE = "csvfile.csv"

def lookup(ID):
    csvfile = open(os.path.join(LOCAL_FOLDER, CSV_FILE), "rU")
    csvFile= csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=",")
    rowNo = 1
    for row in csvFile:
        if row[id] == ID:
            csvfile.close()
            return rowNo
        else:
            rowNo += 1
    csvfile.close()
    return 0

def replace(ID, col, data):
    index = 1
    row = lookup(ID)
    if row == 0:
        return 0
    csvwritefile = open(os.path.join(LOCAL_FOLDER, "temp.csv"), "w")
    csvWriteFile = csv.writer(csvwritefile, delimiter=',', quotechar='"', quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL) #obviously change this if you want a diff quoting format
    csvreadfile = open(os.path.join(LOCAL_FOLDER, CSV_FILE), "rU")
    csvReadFile= csv.reader(csvreadfile, delimiter=",")
    for readrow in csvReadFile:
        if index == row:
            temp = readrow
            temp[col] = data
            csvWriteFile.writerow(temp)
            index += 1
        else:
            index += 1
            csvWriteFile.writerow(readrow)

    csvwritefile.close()
    csvreadfile.close()
    os.rename(os.path.join(LOCAL_FOLDER, "temp.csv"), os.path.join(LOCAL_FOLDER, CSV_FILE))

    return 1
```